# CSS and Internet Explorer div position problems

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

```
body {
background-image: url(pattern.jpeg); background-attachment: fixed;
font-size:12px;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}

 h1,h2,h3
 {
 color : #6685a8;
 }

 div#outer {
width: 960px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
margin-top: 00px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 0px;
border: thin solid #000000;
text-align: left;
 }

 div#header {
padding: 5px;
margin: 0px;
text-align: left;
background-color :#8bb8e8;
 }

 div#nav {
width: 160px;
height: 1669px;
padding: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
float: left;
background-color:#6685a8;
 }

 div#navright {
width: 160px;
height: 1669px;
padding: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
background-color:#6685a8;
  }

 div#main {
float:top;
margin-top: 0px;}

 div#footer {
font-size:12px;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding: 15px;
margin: 0px;
border-top: thin solid #000000;
}
```

Once I create the html for it it just has a small header two sidebars and the main part in the middle(which is just a picture) and the footer contains all the information, it is also all centered on the page.  The problem is it works fine in chrome and firefox, but when I open it in internet explorer it puts the Main.div and the Footer.div below everything, I need it to be at the top between both the nav.div and right.div

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="carguys.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="header" >
    <p>
     </div>
    <div id="nav">
        <img src="" alt="" width="160" height="400" align="middle"/>
    </div>
    <div id="navright">

    </div>
     <div id="main" align="center">
        <img src="" alt="" width="640" height="400"></img>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <h1 align="center">The Show</h1>
     *lots of content in this section, including a table*
    </div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Can you post some HTML? Do you have a link to the page in question?

Comment: the website is not currently out yet

Comment: Does <!DOCTYPE html> add any help? what IE version? here is the code in JSFiddle if anyone is interested: http://jsfiddle.net/z9Xr5/1/

Comment: Most IE problems are related to [invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) and/or something like a bad/missing `doctype` which forces it into quirks mode.

Comment: Eran Medan  The <!DOCTYPE html> works just gotta adjust some of my settings.  Thanks that was a lot more simpler than using the <!--IE--> comment hack.